# sed `D` with address range

Tags: sed

As explained in manual, `D` deletes a portion of the pattern space, up to the first embedded newline. But I can not find any doc explain `D` combined with address ranges. For example:

```
$ cat /tmp/test

accident if I use one.
My wife won't let me buy a power saw.  She is afraid of an

$ cat /tmp/test  | sed -ne '$p;:a;N;$!{ba};2,$D'
accident if I use one.
My wife won't let me buy a power saw.  She is afraid of an
```

Looks like if there are 2 or more lines in pattern space, the first portion till the first embedded newline will be deleted.

Any official doc for it ?

And why `2D` does not work at all?

```
$ cat /tmp/test  | sed -ne '$p;:a;N;$!{ba};2D'
```

Nothing will be shown for above cmd.

Answer (score 0):

`D` with an address line range simply limits when `D` is performed. The address range is like an "IF" clause:

`2,$D` → IF this is line 2 or greater THEN `D`

Equivalently:

`1!D` → IF NOT this is line 1 THEN `D`

---

The reason `2D` leads to no output is because that statement is only reached (in your example) after the `N` loop has loaded line 4 (final line) and the loop has exited. line 4 != line 2 and so `D` is not invoked. We can insert `=` to demonstrate:

```
$ cat /tmp/test | sed -ne '$p;:a;N;$!{ba};=;2D'
4
$
```

`$p` is first invoked after reading line 1 so nothing is printed by it at that point. (IF this is final line THEN `p`. However, line 1 != final line.)

Because `2D` does not cause `D` to happen, `$p` is not reached again. Also, the `-n` argument was provided so there is no default print.